# Select a div inside a div

Tags: jquery

I have a div inside a div:

```
<div id="big">
<div id="small"></div>
</div>
```

They have `display: none;`

A button calls the div inside with jQuery:

```
$("#button").click(function() {

    $("#small").fadeIn("normal");

});
```

Why it don't works? I don't understand?

I also try so many things:

```
$("#big #small").show();
$("#big > #small").show();
$("#big").children().show();
```

Comment: if #big is display:none, then the inner div will remain hidden.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the correct selector in your button code i.e.

```
$("#button").click(function() {

    $("#small").fadeIn("normal");

});
```

The key here is when you say:

> They have `display: none;`

If you make the inner div visible, that doesn't affect the outer div.

You would need to also make the outer div visible like this:

```
$("#button").click(function() {

    $("#big").toggle();
    $("#small").fadeIn("normal");

});
```

Comment: I think I did no explain well what I'm looking for. I want to control the div small and de div big in an independent way, even when, one is inside the other. For instance make the div small fadeIn and div big fadeOut. I think your answer don't solve that problem it just makes big fadeIn (and small fadeIn at the same time)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can't do that. You can't make an inner div fade in while the outer div fades out. If you want to show/hide them independently, you can't put one inside the other.